# appsettings.{ENVIRONMENT}.json not transforming - Deploying asp.net 5 web app to IIS

Tags: asp.net-core

In my publish profile for staging (/Properties/PublishProfiles/xxx.pubxml) I have:

```
<EnvironmentName>Staging</EnvironmentName>
```

I have a file called appsettings.Staging.json.
When I deploy to the server the file stays as appsettings.Staging.json and doesn't get turned into appsettings.json, as I would expect.

Am I missing a step, shouldn't the transformation take place automatically.

The website doesn't work with appsettings.Staging.json file there.

In web.config on the server there is:

```
  <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Staging" />
```

which was added because of the line I added to the publish profile.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is no issue here, I mis-understood how it works.

The website wasn't working because in my DAL (Data Access Library) class library it was looking for a file called appsettings.json so it could get the connection string for EF core, which didn't exist. I changed it to look for appsettings.{environment}.json by getting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable at runtime and it works now.